# TypeError when using Network.connectAsync() from expo-network package

Tags: javascript, react-native, permissions, expo, android-permissions

I'm trying to connect to a WiFi network in my React Native app using the Network.connectAsync() method, but I keep getting a "TypeError: undefined is not a function" error. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import * as Network from 'expo-network';

const connectToWifi = async (ssid, password) => {
    try {
      console.log("first");
      const networkState = await Network.getNetworkStateAsync();
      console.log("2nd");
      if (networkState.isConnected && networkState.type === Network.NetworkStateType.WIFI) {
        console.log('Already connected to WiFi');
      }
      console.log("3rd");
      await Network.requestNetworkAsync({ ssid: ssid, password: password });
      console.log('Connected to WiFi');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error connecting to WiFi: ${error}`);
    }
  };
```

When I call connectToWifi('ssid', 'password'), I get the following error:

Error connecting to WiFi: TypeError: undefined is not a function

I've tried looking at the Expo documentation for Network.connectAsync(), but I can't seem to figure out what's causing the error. Any help would be greatly appreciated!